# Can you launch an Activity Intent from the drop-down navigation in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar

Can you launch an activity using an Intent from ActionBar's drop-down navigation?

```
ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final int itemPosition,long itemId) {
             launchActivity(itemPosition);
             return true;
             }
    };

    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigationListener);
}
```

Here is that method:

```
 protected void launchActivity(int itemPosition) {
     Intent intent;
     switch (itemPosition) {
        case 1:
           intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
        case 2:
           ...
           ...
     }
}
```

This is causing the phone to crash and reboot (looks like out of memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This so simple but really need trick

```
protected void launchActivity(int itemPosition, Context context) {
     Intent intent;
     switch (itemPosition) {
        case 1:
           intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
           break;
        case 2:
           ...
           ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because `onNavigationItemSelected` is getting called when the activity starts - i.e. without the user having selected anything at all from the navigation list.

In your `launchActivity` method, you'll need to detect if the activity to be launched is the one that is already running, if so, don't try and launch another one. What is happening here is that your activity starts, the `onNavigationItemSelected` is fired straight away and your `launchActivity` method is then launching another activity, which is then repeating the process until your device runs out of memory.

You'll need to add code to your `launchActivity` method:

```
protected void launchActivity(int itemPosition) {
    Intent intent;
    switch (itemPosition) {
        case 1:
            if (<this activity is not MyActivity>) {
                intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            ...
            ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You most definitely can launch an activity from the action bar drop down navigation.

Does the activity launch and then crash?